# Efficient way to maintain a lot of independent long running tasks?

Tags: multithreading

Need to listen to response from thousands (and may be more in future) of IMAP servers at the same time. What's an efficient way to do this?

The only solution I can come up with is to create one thread for each connection. Is this the way to go?

FYI, I am going implement this in Ruby, but I guess the language of choice does not matter for this question.

Comment: At least as a general rule, thread-per-connection models thread *quite* poorly. While it could work out, it would not be my first choice (I'd at least consider a thread pool instead). Also note that at least until fairly recently, Ruby had a GIL, so multithreading inside or Ruby proper may gain even less than you'd hope.

Comment: In my case, each connection could last very loog. I though using a fix-sized thread pool with small number of threads might cause most of the IMAP servers to wait for a loog time before getting a chance to connect to my server.

Comment: Try to see if there's an async implementation. Means you'll call asynchronous methods to get your data and provide a callback method to handle the result. This way you'll call the async methods from one thread (async means they're non-blocking) and handle the results with a thread pool/one thread depends on how you want to handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a simple and tested solution:

1) A Request **Listener thread per socket** from which you have to listen to requests (1 if one socket and so on)

2) Put the request in the **processing queue** (Like a producer)

3) Have **Service Threads** that will take those requests and process them (Consumers). You can have multiple consumer threads.

**NOTE: The Service Threads should always use Executors Framework, so that work gets reallocated to threads and threads are reused.**

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising. One question, if there are a lot of sockets that need to be listened on, this will create a lot of listener threads. Will this become a problem? I do realize that each of these listener threads is pretty lightweight - there is not much work for individual one to do.

Comment: No that should not be a problem as the read() call to sockets are blocking and other threads will be given opportunity to be scheduled.

Answer (score 1):

A connection for every thread will only result in [thread-starvation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html) and is not at all recommended. If you are doing it yourself, then I will recommend a thread-pool of size (start with # of cores +1. I think you can still increase the size as it is mainly I/O. Profile and keep an upper count).

(I do not know about ruby and threads (Ruby I guess has [GIL](http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/) issues) so probably a process)

But what is recommended is to let a web-server do it for you. For example, use a web-server which takes request's and you do the logic. Web-servers are suitably more designed than manual tweaks to handle such situations.

Comment: Thanks, Jatin! But one problem is, I need to listen to all those IMAP servers for new mails. My first thought is to issue an IMAP IDLE command and let the IMAP servers push updates to my server. However, the IDLE command blocks the current thread until an IDLE_DONE command is issued. This is different from a typical http request which has a lifespan. While I could do connecting to a IMAP server, authenticating, fetching new mails and disconnecting, but this will introduce significant overhead compared to using IDLE. Any idea?

Comment: JRuby does not have the GIL issue.

Comment: In Java, I would then do using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool(). What it does basically depending upon the load, makes new threads. And when a job is done (IDLE_DONE) it will not destroy that thread but rather keep it active (sleep/blocked) for the next request. Hence reusing resources

Comment: @Jatin Listener threads would always be in `while(run){ read() }` loop so even if you use Executors it wont be much beneficial

Comment: @NarendraPathai I disagree. The worker threads are blocked in any implementation of THreadPoolExecutor

Comment: Hey @Jatin when did I say that worker threads in pool are blocked! In case I said it it may be a mistake. But if the Runnable you are submitting to the Pool is never going to exit, you are utilizing that Worker thread forever and not using the reuse available. That is why at that place (Listening) I am more in favor of using individual Thread than Pool.

Comment: @NarendraPathai Hey. I thinkt here is some miscommunication. Yes absolutely I agree with you. By blocked I meant if the operation was over. Like you said, here in this case as the loop is not exited, it is never terminated. True

Comment: @Jatin that's ok man!! It's good that we are having constructive discussions! Isn't it? :)